# JSX returns content as a string rather than html, or commas between html

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple demo that generates star icons where the quantity is determined by the `ratingstars` key. However, the problem is that the component returns part html and part string.

Take this as an example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

class ReviewsTotalStars extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ratingStars: 3
    };
  }

  makeStars = qty => {
    const stars = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
      stars.push('<i class="fas fa-star" key="' + i + '"></i>');
    }
    return stars;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="reviews-total-stars" data-rating={this.state.ratingStars}>
        {this.makeStars(this.state.ratingStars)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<ReviewsTotalStars />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hfnphp

The specific problem is the stars returning as a string. I know from reading other stackoverflow posts that you can use the 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' attribute, so I changed it to the following:

```
<div id="reviews-total-stars" data-rating={this.state.ratingStars} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.makeStars(this.state.ratingStars)}}>
</div>
```

This *almost* did the trick, but there seemed to be commas between each star.

How can I get the component to output all html and nothing as a string, and with no commas between each star? Also, am I going about this in the best way, or is there a better approach to generating each star's html given that the `ratingStars` key determines the number of stars to output?

Thanks for any help here as I'm new to React.

Comment: Just dont use strings. Push components to the array, not strings.

Comment: Yes, simply remove the double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In react there are much better and cleaner ways to do what you want.

```
class ReviewsTotalStars extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ratingStars: 3
    };
  }

  makeStars = qty => {
    const stars = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
      stars.push(0); // push 0 as a placeholder
    }
    // return collection of jsx not strings
    return stars.map((item,i)=><i className="fas fa-star" key={i}></i>)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="reviews-total-stars" data-rating={this.state.ratingStars}>
        {this.makeStars(this.state.ratingStars)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your concept, but it doesn't work - see this demo with your code in: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rbcryw?file=index.js - it doesn't output anything unless I put the <i> part in quotes, and the key doesn't work. Can you help?

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to pass `i` argument to a map function. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly inside your render function using the map function:

```
<div id="reviews-total-stars" data-rating={this.state.ratingStars}>
        {Array(this.state.ratingStars).fill(0).map((_,i) => <i key={i} className="fas fa-star"/>)}
</div>
```

The way it works is that I first create an array with a size of this.state.ratingStars. Then I map this array to create the star icons

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

class ReviewsTotalStars extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ratingStars: 3
    };
  }

  makeStars = qty => {
    let stars = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
      stars += '<i class="fas fa-star" key="' + i + '">Some value</i><br/>';
    }
    return stars;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id="reviews-total-stars"
        data-rating={this.state.ratingStars}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: this.makeStars(this.state.ratingStars)
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

render(<ReviewsTotalStars />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I think this solution is not really what is react about.
React is all abouts components - why creating ugly strings and than put them in aa element when you directly can add / create elements.